# How to extract line profile (ray trace line) through 3d matrix (ndarray 3-dim) by specifying initial & final point

Tags: python, scikit-image

This seems like a fairly simple problem, and I haven't been able to find a canned solution. Essentially, this would be the `3d` equivalent of `skimage.measure` profile_line

Consider a matrix A, with dimensions (i,j,k). Each matrix element is a number. In real terms, consider this a voxelized 3 dimensional temperature distribution.

I would like an efficient method to extract a line profile (a ray trace line) through this data from point (i_1,j_1,k_1) to (i_2,j_2,k_2). Or, similarly, defining an initial point (i_1,j_1,k_1) and a line trajectory using theta, phi and radius in polar coordinates.

I recognize an accurate result would consider boundary crossing and partial voxel volumes along the path, but I would be satisfied with a crude approximation which samples nearest voxel values with a regular step size (say, 0.1*voxel dimension) along the ray trace line.

Help is much appreciated. I am happy to describe further as needed,

#### It would be nice if this worked..

```
from skimage.measure import profile_line

line = profile_line(3dim_ndarray, (i1,j1,k1), (i2,j2,k2))
print(line)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fyi, we have a long-standing PR for 3D `profile_line` [here](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/pull/1884#issue-56460545). You might find some inspiration there.

However, the difficulty and reason why it hasn't been merged yet is that averaging over a cylinder is harder than averaging over a rectangle, as in `profile_line` (2D). If you don't need averaging, it is reasonably easy to implement with SciPy:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage as ndi, spatial

def profile_line(image, start_coords, end_coords, *,
                 spacing=1, order=0, endpoint=True):
    coords = []
    n_points = int(np.ceil(spatial.distance.euclidean(start_coords, end_coords)
                           / spacing))
    for s, e in zip(start_coords, end_coords):
        coords.append(np.linspace(s, e, n_points, endpoint=endpoint))
    profile = ndi.map_coordinates(image, coords, order=order)
    return profile
```

order is the order of the interpolation: default 0 above, ie value of nearest voxel, but can be 1 (linear interpolation) or 3 (cubic interpolation). The best choice depends on your needs.

There's also various design choices to be made, e.g. instead of `np.ceil` you might want to instead calculate what the endpoint *should* be so that the spacing itself is exact. e.g. if the distance between start and end is 2.5, then your profile might include 3 points and will end 0.5 voxels short of the endpoint you specified. In the implementation above, you will get 3 points between the start and endpoint, but the real spacing will end up being 2.5/3 = 0.8333, instead of 1.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks so much!   minor correction... "profile = ndi.map_coordinates" --> "profile = ndimage.map_coordinates"

Comment: Oops! Normally I `import as`. Fixed! (By aliasing the import.) Thanks for pointing it out! =)